# Calc 3 triple integral bounds

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates

I was given a region below a hemisphere of $z=\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$ and $z=3$ in the order of $dr\cdot dz \cdot d \theta$ for Cartesian and $dp\cdot d \phi\cdot d \theta$ for spherical. I tried finding the bounds for $r$ and I had $0$ to $\sqrt{25-z^2}$ but I asked a friend and he told me that we were supposed to set the $z$ equal to each other and solve for the radius or should I do that for the spherical coordinates only? Sorry if it’s confusing I’ll try to describe further if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

So the bounds we have are: $$3\le z\le \sqrt {25-x^2-y^2} $$ Now, considering the shape of our graph (i.e. Dome-shaped) we can use cylindrical coordinate. As you know: $$x^2+y^2=r^2 \implies 3 \le\ z\le \sqrt{25-r^2}$$ Since the graph $\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$ projects a circle on the $x-y$   axis, we can deduce $0\le \theta \le 2\pi $.

Also, Notice $r$ is maximum when $z=3$, because that is when we have the largest circle projected on $x-y$ axis. Now, to get the upper bound for $r$ we must set $z=3$:$$3=\sqrt{25-r^2}$$$$9=25-r^2$$$$r^2=16$$$$r=4$$
Therefore, $0\le r\le 4$.

Keeping those in mind, our integral then becomes $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_3^{\sqrt{25-r^2}}rdzdrd\theta$$

---

$(r\rightarrow z )\land(z\rightarrow r)$

---

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^4\int_3^{\sqrt{25-z^2}}zdrdzd\theta$$

Comment: I was given the order of dr dz dtheta so does that mean I would just switch the integrals or for the first integral it would be 0 to sqrt(25-z^2)?

Comment: @luke Once you convert a function $f(x)$ to, let us say, $g(y)$ and you also map the differential in the case of the example $dx\implies \alpha dy$. Then, it does not matter how you integrate. That is, you can integrate with respect to any variable you want. Just keep in mind, integrate with respect to the variable that has another variable embedded in it first. In this case, integrate with respect to $z$ because $r$ is hidden in it, so to say. If you integrate with respect to $r$ first then you will get stuck once you integrate with respect to $z$; Notice there is a $r$ in the bounds of $z$.

Comment: @betrand wittgenstein's Ghost ,? but if I use the equation r=sqrt(25-z^2) then for dz do from 3 to 5 could that work?

Comment: @Luke No, that wont work. How did you get the bounds 3 to 5 anyways? It does not occur anywhere.

Comment: Well  I solved for z in the equation of r=sqrt(25-z^2) set equal to zero on the inside to get 5 for z as an upper bound and 3 as a lower bound as that is the plane

Comment: Recall, $x^2+y^2=r^2\neq z^2$, this equality is the result of how we transform a cartesian function to cylindrical fucntion. However, If you **really** **really** want to integrate with respect to $r$ first, then just change all the instances of $z\rightarrow r\land r\rightarrow z$.

Answer (score 0):

[similar answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3I6a.png)

Found a similar answer to this that makes it possible to be integrated that way